# How to copy self signed certificate into Client computer Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store

Tags: java, https, applet, certificate, ssl-certificate

Ok I created this self signed certificate.  I'm just wondering if it is possible to do a basic Java File copy into the clients Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store.  Is this an actual folder that exists in clients C drive?

I have an Applet with full access and I want it to manually drop my self signed certificate into the clients computer.

The reason for this is that I don't want the user to manually accept the self signed certificate and place it under the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store in IE.

Is this possible?